# .htaccess - rewriting url requests and taking care of resource files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I thought i should open a new question for a matter related to my previous one (you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22494033/htaccess-rewriting-url-requests-and-taking-care-of-css-files)). The situation is very similar to that question, but i found a different approach, and would like to know if it's correct.

I wanted to rewrite the urls for my site, and being able to take care of resource files (css, js, images, etc) so that browser doenn't search for them in the wrong directory.

Following are snippets of the html code of a sample page found browsing for example to `articles/writer/erenor` (here htaccess rewrites the url to `/articles.php?writer=erenor`, and this part works well).

Into `<head>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./inc-javascript-files/jquery.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
  @import url(./inc-css-files/index.css);
</style>
```

Into `<body>` tag:

```
<img alt="Avatar" src="./inc-images-files/avatar.png">
<img alt="Pattern" src="./inc-images-files/pattern/violet.png">
<br><br>
<a href="/articles/writer/erenor">Writer Erenor</a>
```

Now, i have this snippet from .htaccess file:

```
# take care of resource files
RewriteRule inc\-(css|javascript|images)\-files/(.*)\.(png|jp[e]g|gif|js|css) includes-$1/$2.$3 [L]

# url rewriting
RewriteRule ^articles/writer/(\w*)/?$ articles.php?writer=$1
```

And, finally, the example of the file structure:

```
/mysite
/mysite/.htaccess    //this is the htaccess file we are talking about ;-)
/mysite/articles.php
/mysite/includes-css
/mysite/includes-css/index.css
/mysite/includes-javascript
/mysite/includes-javascript/jquery.js
/mysite/includes-images
/mysite/includes-images/avatar.png
/mysite/includes-images/pattern
/mysite/includes-images/pattern/violet.png
```

I just tested the code, and it seems to work: my browser asks for the css file (searching it in the "wrong" place) and it retrieves it correctly, so i'm quite happy with it :)
Links in the page will be like the one in the html shown above, which seems to work well.

Questions:
1. Is this a good approach to be able to avoid browsers requests to resources being in the "wrong" place? (I know that i will have to add more parameters when it comes to other files like for example videos, txt's, tga, etc etc etc)
2. Should i move this site to production server, will it work without modifications? In other words, is this a kind of "box" that can be moved here and there easily?

A little note: since these are just code snippets, tell me if something appears to be missing..maybe i just forgot to copy/paste it ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be requesting the files in the current directory. Why do you do that? Why don't you request the from the site root? (remove the '.'). If I read it correctly, on `/articles/writer/asdf` and `/articles/writer/zxcv` the files will request `/articles/writer/asdf/inc-css-files/index.css` and `/articles/writer/zxcv/inc-css-files/index.css`. The browser sees this as two different files. If the user requests 100 writers, it will download index.css 100 times, and caches the same file 100 times under different names. That is wasteful.

I recommend requesting the files relative to the site root instead if you have the files stored in a folder in the site root.

Comment: That would give me a problem when i move the site a folder up (or down) the structure. For example, right now i have the site in `/mysite/`, but what will happen when i'll move it to `/`? You're still right about the caching of multiple identical files, thought. Even if i usually leave a timestamp on those css and js files, to always get the last version, in case of updates or whatever on those files..

Comment: Then the question is: Why would you want to do that? Once you settle on a certain url structure, you'll have to keep using that url structure for quite some time. It's not that it changes every couple of days. You are also already using a rewriterule to direct requests to the right spot. As long as that .htaccess file stays in your www-root, you can simply change that line to point at the new location of your includes and the problem is solved.

Comment: Well, because i'm right now working on my development site, and when i move to production, i want to make the fewest possible changes. But, i also want to find something that can be used almost everywhere, so that i can produce a sort of "box" working without external intervention. That's a poor sentence, i know, but i hope you will understand :)

Comment: By the way..to fix that "multiple requests for the same file", i will change the links to be relative to the root of the site: this, because, anyway, i'm going to redirect them to correct position; but, of course, if the browser finds similar requests for resource files, they will only cache them once. That's absolutely correct :)